# How to iterate through an enum summing the sizeof(s) of classes with the same name

Tags: c++, templates, preprocessor

I have an enum with variables names v1, v2..., vn, and each name has a corresponding class with the same name. I want to find, in compile time (even though I don't know if it's possible in run time either), the sum of the sizeof of these classes, as in the example below. Can you do this using templates or the preprocessor?

```
enum class Enum
{
    First,
    A = First,
    B,
    C,
    Last
};
class A
{
    // ...
};
class B
{
    // ...
};
class C
{
    // ...
};
constexpr size_t GetTotSumSizeOf()
{
    // iterate from Enum::First to Enum::Last, summing sizeof the corresponding class
}
static constexpr size_t TotSum = GetTotSumSizeOf();
```

Comment: Neither **templates** nor **preprocessor**.  You need to use **reflection**, but (unfortunately) that feature hasn't made it to C++ yet.  In the mean time, you'd need to write the connective tissue manually.

Comment: Does this *need* to be an `enum`?

Comment: each class must have an associated, auto incremented, id

Comment: This is not possible, as described, in C++, for fundamental reasons. C++ does not work this way, on a fundamental level. However, something that's logically equivalent to this can be accomplished by using additional scripts, that generate the appropriate code, both the enum and the C++ expression, as code, but that's not what's asked here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

c++ does not allow you to iterate over enum class directly. so you can achiene the desired result by creating a helper struct that maps each enum value to its correponding class and then recursively compute the sum using templates.
create a template specialization of the EnumToClass struct for each enum value. and use the GetSizeOfHelper template function that recursively computes the sum of th size of the corresponding class.finally use GetToSumSizeof function to call the recursive function and wrap it.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

enum class Enum
{
    First,
    A = First,
    B,
    C,
    Last
};

class A
{
    // ...
};

class B
{
    // ...
};

class C
{
    // ...
};

template<Enum E>
struct EnumToClass;

template<>
struct EnumToClass<Enum::A>
{
    using Type = A;
};

template<>
struct EnumToClass<Enum::B>
{
    using Type = B;
};

template<>
struct EnumToClass<Enum::C>
{
    using Type = C;
};

template<Enum E>
constexpr size_t GetSizeOfHelper()
{
    if constexpr (E == Enum::Last)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        using ClassType = typename EnumToClass<E>::Type;
        return sizeof(ClassType) + GetSizeOfHelper<static_cast<Enum>(static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<Enum>>(E) + 1)>();
    }
}

constexpr size_t GetTotSumSizeOf()
{
    return GetSizeOfHelper<Enum::First>();
}

static constexpr size_t TotSum = GetTotSumSizeOf();

int main()
{
    // Use TotalSum
    char buffer[TotSum];

   // Print the value of TotSum
   std::cout << "Total size of the classes: " << TotSum << std::endl;

   // Example usage of buffer
   A* a_ptr = reinterpret_cast<A*>(&buffer[0]);
   B* b_ptr = reinterpret_cast<B*>(&buffer[sizeof(A)]);
   C* c_ptr = reinterpret_cast<C*>(&buffer[sizeof(A) + sizeof(B)]);
    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a constexpr routine to return the information of the class by it's Enum identifier, and then sum up that information in your constexpr `GetTotSumSizeOf`.

The association of Enum identifier and class name is manual.  There is nothing in the language that ties them together or enforces that they are correct.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using std::cout;
using std::size_t;
using std::underlying_type_t;

enum class Enum
{
    First,
    A = First,
    B,  
    C,  
    Last
};
constexpr
auto operator++(Enum& e) -> Enum& {
    using UEnum = underlying_type_t<Enum>;
    auto ue = static_cast<UEnum>(e);
    e = static_cast<Enum>(ue + 1); 
    return e;
}

class A
{
    // ...
};
class B
{
    // ...
};
class C
{
    // ...
};

constexpr auto SizeBy(Enum e) -> size_t {
    if (e == Enum::A) return sizeof(A);
    if (e == Enum::B) return sizeof(B);
    if (e == Enum::C) return sizeof(C);
    return 0;
}

constexpr size_t GetTotSumSizeOf() {
    size_t result{};

    for (Enum i = Enum::First; i != Enum::Last; ++i) {
        result += SizeBy(i);
    }   

    return result;
}
static constexpr size_t TotSum = GetTotSumSizeOf();

int main() {
    cout << TotSum << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming from your comment that an actual `enum` is not required, you can list your classes via the type system and build the identifier generation on top of it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>

template <class...> struct typelist {};

template <class... Classes>
constexpr auto total_sizeof(typelist<Classes...>) {
    return (sizeof(Classes) + ...);
}

template <class Class, class... Classes>
constexpr auto class_id(typelist<Classes...>) {
    return []<std::size_t... Idx>(std::index_sequence<Idx...>) {
        return ((std::is_same_v<Class, Classes> * Idx) + ...);
    }(std::index_sequence_for<Classes...>{});
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

constexpr typelist<struct A, struct B, struct C> all_classes;

struct A { char a[1]; };
struct B { char b[2]; };
struct C { char c[3]; };

int main() {
    static_assert(class_id<A>(all_classes) == 0);
    static_assert(class_id<B>(all_classes) == 1);
    static_assert(class_id<C>(all_classes) == 2);
    static_assert(total_sizeof(all_classes) == sizeof(A) + sizeof(B) + sizeof(C));
}
```

[See it live on godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/5bsPcEebT)

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, one option is using external scripts to generate the enum class and the total_size variable, but that is not very maintainable. Even if you automatically configure the script to be run before each compilation, it adds bloat to compilation time, besides the IDE going crazy with undefined symbols during development. So I think it's best to specify manually.

A simpler construct I came up with uses a single static_assert to make sure the programmer remembered to specify the same number of classes as enum values.

```
constexpr size_t GetTotSumSizeOf()
{
    constexpr size_t LENS[]
    {
        sizeof(A),
        sizeof(B),
        sizeof(C),
    };
    static_assert(sizeof(LENS) / sizeof(*LENS) == (size_t)Enum::Last);
    return std::accumulate(LENS, LENS + (size_t)Enum::Last, size_t(0));
}
```

However, this approach isn't safe against an accidental change in the enum variable name and forgetting to update the corresponding sizeof(), which is why I accepted 곽지훈's answer, as I think it's the most reliable.